# Make the heading of the page changing color every time the user clicks on it

Tags: javascript, events

Make the heading of the page changing color every time the user clicks on it

```
function makeItClickable() {
    var myColors = ['red', 'purple', '#E84751', 'blue', 'orange', '#323643'];
    document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
      for(i = 0; i < myColors.length; i++) {
        this.style.color = myColors[i];
      }
    });
  }
```

It does works only one time !
I need vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

You do not want a loop

```js
const myColors = ['red', 'purple', '#E84751', 'blue', 'orange', '#323643'];
let cnt = 0;

document.querySelector('h1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (cnt >= myColors.length) cnt = 0; // reset
  this.style.color = myColors[cnt];
  cnt++;
})
```

```html
<h1>This is a header</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the current index into a variable, then update your style. Cycle throw the array once you get to the end (using the [modulus](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/760/remainder---modulus----) operator to make the code compact). Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmujqyv8/).

**HTML**

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
let i = 0;

let colors = [
   'red', 
   'purple', 
   '#E84751', 
   'blue', 
   'orange', 
   '#323643'
];

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
   // Increase the counter, reset it when end is reached
   i = (i + 1) % colors.length;

   this.style.color = colors[i];
}
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are not recommended. I do like the % though

Comment: I updated the proposed answer with JavaScript minded event.